# highlight.js with highlightjs-line-numbers changes code font

Tags: jekyll, highlight.js, highlightjs

I have a [Jekyll blog](https://github.com/wermos/blog), where I changed the code highlighter from Rouge (the default) to `highlight.js`, and it works perfectly.

However, I also want line numbers on my code snippets. Since `highlight.js` does not provide line numbers by default, I turned to the [`highlightjs-line-numbers`](https://github.com/wcoder/highlightjs-line-numbers.js) plugin.

I followed the instructions given in the [`highlightjs-line-numbers` usage instructions](https://github.com/wcoder/highlightjs-line-numbers.js#usage), and added the relevant lines to my [`_includes/script.html`](https://github.com/wermos/blog/blob/custom-liquid-tag/_includes/scripts.html).

However, for some reason, adding this plugin mysteriously changes the code font to Arial. Here is a [link to a blog post](https://wermos.github.io/blog/jekyll/update/welcome-to-jekyll/) which demonstrates this odd side effect.

I have tried to figure this issue out for hours, to no avail. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong, and why this code font change is occurring?

Edit: The current GH Pages is being built from the `custom-liquid-tag` branch of [my repository](https://github.com/wermos/blog), and not `main`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a sort of last-ditch effort, I opened [an issue](https://github.com/wcoder/highlightjs-line-numbers.js/issues/93) on the [`highlightjs-line-numbers`](https://github.com/wcoder/highlightjs-line-numbers.js/) repo to get some feedback from the author of the library himself.

Luckily for me, he responded, and the solution he proposed was indeed correct:

In my repository, the theme I am using, [minimal-mistakes](https://github.com/mmistakes/minimal-mistakes), was overriding the `table` CSS style and breaking the font. Since the line numbers plugin uses the `table` CSS style, the end result was a messed up font.

The error went away after I manually added

```css
table {
  font-family: $monospace;
}
```

to my `main.scss`.

For the sake of completeness, [here is a link](https://github.com/mmistakes/minimal-mistakes/blob/8a67ce8e41ec850f2d7c373aa47739b2abfee6f1/_sass/minimal-mistakes/_variables.scss#L19) to how `minimal-mistakes` defines `$monospace`.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Answer**

This answer was not able to help OP with the problem. Keeping this answer here so the comments remain intaked.

**Original Answer**

I think you are missing the import of the highlightjs stylesheet that goes with the highlight JavaScript in your file `scripts.html` [1]

`https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/11.6.0/styles/default.min.css`

[1] https://github.com/wermos/blog/blob/main/_includes/scripts.html

Comment: Unfortunately, adding that line didn't work. Note that I _am_ importing a style [here](https://github.com/wermos/blog/blob/main/_includes/scripts.html#L370): the Monokai Sublime style.

Also, sorry for not making it clear: the current gh-pages is being built from the `custom-liquid-tag` branch. The `main` branch has the working blog code, but without the line numbers.

Comment: Ah, my mistake on overlooking the Monokai stylesheet. My eyes were too focused on looking for `default.min.css`. I am out of suggestions on what could help with your situation.

Comment: No worries! I managed to figure out the issue via some other means. I'll be writing my own answer shortly, on the off chance that someone else stumbles into the same issue.